# Jailkit not working properly when connecting remotely from iPad via SFTP app

Tags: ssh, sftp, account-restrictions

I used jailkit to add users and restrict them to a jail directory. It works for Linux and PC clients connecting to the ssh server but when I connect with iPad it gives them access to everything.

I am using my iPad to connect to the SSH server on my linux PC using an SFTP app. I'm logging in with a username. When I log in using the username from a PC it works, restricting me to the jail root folder. But from my iPad it lets me access the entire file system.

I used this tutorial:

http://syiron.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/simple-jailkit-howto/

Comment: Are you using iPad as your ssh client or trying to get jailkit working on iPad?

Comment: I am using my iPad to connect to the SSH server on my linux PC using an SFTP app. Logging in with a username. When I logon using the username from a PC it works, restricting me to the jail root folder. But on iPad it lets me access the entire file system.

Comment: Are you sure you're logging in to the same account? Post your `sshd_config`, the user's `passwd` entry and the user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.